# checking availability between 2 dates not working

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have a order page when you can order cars. I have 2 functions, 1 to order 1 to check.

**My order function:**

```
function reserveer($resvan,$restot,$autoid){
    $con = new Core();
    $con->connect();
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO reservering (resvan, restot,autoid) VALUES (?,?,?)';
    
    if ($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $resvan, $restot,$autoid);
        $stmt->execute();   
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else{
        die("errormessage: " . $con->myconn->error);
    }
}
```

**my check function:**

```
function check($resvan, $restot,$autoid){
    $con = new Core();
    $con->connect();
    $errmsg = array();
    $sqlres = 'SELECT * FROM reservering WHERE resvan >= ? AND restot <= ? AND autoid=?';
    if($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sqlres)){
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $resvan, $restot,$autoid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
    }
    if ($stmt->fetch()){
        $errmsg[] = "already exists!";
        return $errmsg;
    }
}
```

But I have a flaw in my code. When someone orders from 2001-01-01 to 2001-01-15 it gets correctly inserted. And when someone orders from 2001-01-02 to 2001-01-14 it gets inserted aswell. I thought this would work. I've tried the sql BETWEEN aswell but that doesn't work either.

So my question is, how can I make a correct check for this? I have no errors.

My table setup :

[image: Table]

Comment: What datatype are you using for your dates in the database table? (please don't say that you're using a varchar)

Comment: No I'm using date @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When someone orders from 2001-01-01 to 2001-01-15 it gets correctly inserted

We have

```
resvan=2001-01-01
restot=2001-01-15
```

Now look at your query which checks the reservation

```
WHERE resvan >= ? AND restot <= ?
```

> And when someone orders from 2001-01-02 to 2001-01-14 it gets inserted aswell

So when that happens your query becomes

```
WHERE resvan >= 2001-01-02 AND restot <= 2001-01-14
```

This does not return a duplicate because no such record exists. Your existing record had date starting on 1st january, not second january.

Solution is very simple, you do not want to double book a car on a date which it is already booked for so just provide it 1 date and not both to match. Even if 1 matches don't re-book

```
WHERE (
2001-01-02 BETWEEN resvan AND restot
OR 2001-01-14 BETWEEN resvan AND restot
)
AND autoid=?
```

Now try with those those new dates

Comment: Oh yeah, thats true. But how would I make it different? What would be a solution for this?

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. It even gives a already exists on dates where theres not even a booking. And you can still book between 2 dates.

Comment: Probably i need some sleep because i have a feeling even this one is not accurate :P

Comment: I used this code for a while now but I just realized a flaw in it today. If someone orders something on 02-03 to 02-03 but then if someone orders from 02-02 to 02-04 it says succesfully ordered? How can I fix that? It shouldn't be available then for those people. I can't seem to find a solution.